# Executing su user (without password) on paramiko ssh connection

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko, su

I need to login in ssh to a server, do "su username" (without password) to execute some commands as that user (that have no direct login in ssh).

From the terminal it would be something like this:

```
root@cs01:~# su foo
foo@cs01:/root$ cd
foo@cs01:~$ ls
```

I've tried to do this with paramiko (python):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('host', username='root', password='mypassword', key_filename='<filename>')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su foo')
print stdout.readlines()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd')
print stdout.readlines()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('pwd')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

But the script doesn't end.

Logs are these:

```
...
DEB [20111207-16:22:25.538] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20111207-16:22:25.921] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEB [20111207-16:22:25.923] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEB [20111207-16:22:26.088] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
INF [20111207-16:22:26.088] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEB [20111207-16:22:26.151] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
```

If i try only this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su foo')
#without print
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('pwd')
print stdout.readlines()
```

it executes the pwd as root, not as foo.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `exec_command()` call happens in a new shell, so there is no state carried over from previous commands. If commands rely on a previous command to execute, you have to send them in a single statement, or as a script. If you want an interactive shell, there is the `invoke_shell` command, but then you need to parse the shell output to simulate interactive use (the pexpect library can be used here).

You can use the `sudo` command, or `su -c` to execute the command.. However, I would suggest configuring a secure login for the needed user, and connecting as that user directly.

Comment: thx. my goal is to call su user, then cd (to go to his home), and then svn up on that directory. There's a way to concatenate this, or to mantain state in paramiko?

Comment: `su foo -c "svn up /home/foo"` is one possibility. Script it out on the commandline first, as this has nothing to do with paramiko. It's not that you can't "maintain state" in paramiko, it's that you're executing two independent shells.